# ¿Cómo contar múltiples valores de propiedades en una matriz de objetos usando lodash?

Tags: typescript, nestjs, lodash

Hola que tal tengo este JSON retornado por un api de Nest

```
 const findAsistenciaWeek = [
    {
      "uuid": "11cb1f3d-8fb5-4173-8f94-71dc56d77146",
      "asistencia": {
        "fechaEntrada": "2023-02-08"
      },
      "alumno": {
        "uuid": "a6bbc480-98f9-4df2-9430-01730a4b097f",
        "inscripcion": [
          {
            "uuid": "f9530d8b-df46-4572-9024-50fa4d636f32",
            "curso": {
              "nivel": "MATERNAL",
              "estatus": true
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
...
  ]
```

Usando la libreria lodash quiero saber cuantos alumnos ingresaron el el dia, de acuerdo al nivel cursado

He intentado de diversas maneras y hasta ahorita tengo esto

```
   const totalAsistenciasPorSemana = lodash.countBy(findAsistenciasWeek, 'asistencia.fechaEntrada');
```

Sin embargo el código de arriba me arrija esto

```
totalAsistenciasPorSemana = {
    "2023-02-08": 5,
    "2023-02-09": 7
  }
```

Pero el resultado que espero es el siguiente (Ejemplo)

```
totalAsistenciasPorSemana = {
    "2023-02-08": {
"maternal":3
"preescolar":1
"primaria":1
},
    "2023-02-09": {
"maternal":2
"preescolar":2
"primaria":3
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya quedo solucionado utilizando este código`

```
 const asistenciasSemana = lodash
      .chain(findAsistenciasWeek)
      .groupBy('asistencia.fechaEntrada')
      .map(a => ({
        fecha: a[0].asistencia.fechaEntrada,
        niveles: lodash.countBy(a, 'alumno.inscripcion[0].curso.nivel'),
      }));
```

y el resultado es el siguiente:

```
 "asistenciasSemana": [
    {
      "fecha": "2023-02-08",
      "niveles": {
        "MATERNAL": 3,
        "PREESCOLAR": 1,
        "PRIMARIA": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "fecha": "2023-02-09",
      "niveles": {
        "MATERNAL": 2,
        "PREESCOLAR": 2,
        "PRIMARIA": 3
      }
    }
  ]
```